# Javascript element.style.backgroundImage not loading image

Tags: javascript, html, css

Not sure what I'm missing here...

```
window.onload = function() {
    var testDiv = document.createElement("div");
    testDiv.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/2000px-Smiley.svg.png')";

    document.body.appendChild(testDiv);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you're setting a `background-image` on a div with no `height` or `width`. Add those:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var testDiv = document.createElement("div");
    testDiv.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/2000px-Smiley.svg.png')";
    testDiv.style.backgroundSize="cover"; //image is large, you dont need this if you dont want
    testDiv.style.height="100px"; //add some value
    testDiv.style.width="100px"; //add some value

    document.body.appendChild(testDiv);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nscaumgq/)

Comment: Ah ok, thanks alot.  Will mark this as the answer.  Also, thanks for introducing me to the backgroundSize property, hadn't even heard of it before.  Something new :)  I was hoping it would be smart enough to detect the image size and set the div accordingly.  Would have saved me 2 lines of code lol.